# Can problems of class P be transformed into SAT formula?

Tags: satisfiability

I know that NP problems can be transformed into SAT (due to this fact, SAT is considered to be a NP Complete problem). I am not sure if P problems can too be transformed into SAT.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can since $P \subseteq NP$.

Comment: Exercise: Does $NP \subseteq P$ hold?

Comment: Isn't this a open problem?

Comment: @SiluPanda "⊆" means "subset of **or** equal to".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can because P class is included in NP class, you can convert every P problem into 3-SAT in (at most) polynomial time.